# How can I get rid of the ./ and ../ in the ls output

Tags: bash, terminal, sh, ls

I want to remove the .. and . entry in the `ls` output. How ever, running

```
ls . | sed '/^\.\./d;/^\.\//d'
```

doesn't work for me (`./` is still here) and I can't figure out why.

Comment: BTW, [`ls` is not an appropriate tool for programmatic use](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs); attempts to use its output in your software *will* cause bugs if you run into interesting filenames or are run on a platform with behavior that differs from where you did your testing. If you're trying to use it interactively, by contrast, https://superuser.com/ is the right place for questions about *using* tools rather than developing them.

Comment: `ls .` does not show the entries of `.`. or `..`. Is there an alias for `ls`? What's your OS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ls` has `-A` option exactly for this purpose:

```
ls -A
```

From `man ls`:

```
-A, --almost-all
              do not list implied . and ..
```

Comment: Notably, this is a BSD extension not guaranteed by POSIX.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Available on GNU systems too.

Comment: "Not guaranteed by POSIX" was intended to be the operative text. Yes, there's plenty of cross-pollination between GNU and BSD extensions.

Answer (score 1):

By default `ls` does not print those entries in the first place, nor any others whose names begin with `.`.  Nor does it print a trailing slash after directory names.  That your plain `ls` command is doing those things suggests that you have an alias (most likely) or possibly a shell function by that name in your environment.  You can list the current aliases in your shell environment with the command `alias -p`.

Either way, you can sidestep the alias / function without removing it by using an absolute path: `/bin/ls`.  In the case of an alias, at least, you can probably specify the `-A` option to suppress `.` and `..`, but if that (non-standard) option is supported with the meaning it has for GNU and BSD `ls` then it will not suppress other dotfiles (which may be exactly what you want).